# pandas not showing output in pyCharm but showing in google colab

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, pycharm

```py
import pandas as pd
kulfi=['Chocolate','Mango','Vanilla','Kesar']
pd.Series(kulfi)
```

When I run this program in pyCharm it doesn't show any output in console whereas it shows output in Google Colab
Please note that I have already pip3 installed python-tk for Graphical output(if needed)

Comment: This behaviour is expected. Wrap the last line in `print()` to get the same result in PyCharm, or any other tool that is not a Jupyter/Colab notebook.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `print(pd.Series(kulfi))`. They are different environments. Google Colab has an interactive Jupyter notebook like interface while pycharm is an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen anytime while using various IDE's. `Google Colab` has various things already done for you, it means `colab` knows you are wanting the output. So, here you have to specify the `print(pd.Series(kulfi))` to get everything going. In case of any IDE you have to specifically mention the print statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected output since you are not using `print()` function.
Please use the following way to get the desired result in pycharm or anyother console.

```
import pandas as pd
kulfi=['Chocolate','Mango','Vanilla','Kesar']
print(pd.Series(kulfi))
```